# tomcat start service NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: services, tomcat

I am trying to redeploy my server on a new server with a different DNS and IP address.  Therefore, I think my problem is in the configuration to find JAR files.  Is there a way to get more detail as to which class is being requested so I can narrow down my problem.

Does anyone have any suggested troubleshooting guidance for such problem?

BTW - the configuration was working on the original server, and I tried to find all the locations in the files: conf/, worker.properties, server.xml, catalina.policy, web.xml.

The jarkarta.log repeats the starting... error initializing ... forever.  Very boring, therefore, the problem has to be fundamental.

Apparently, the error message is recorded in the log across more than one line and would be this:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError : java/lang/Object

```
[2012-05-21 18:20:33] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2012-05-21 18:20:33] [info] Running Service...
[2012-05-21 18:20:33] [info] Starting service...
[2012-05-21 18:20:33] [info] Error occurred during initialization of VM
[2012-05-21 18:20:33] [info] java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError
[2012-05-21 18:20:33] [info] : java/lang/Object
[2012-05-21 18:21:59] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2012-05-21 18:21:59] [info] Running Service...
[2012-05-21 18:21:59] [info] Starting service...
[2012-05-21 18:21:59] [info] Error occurred during initialization of VM
[2012-05-21 18:21:59] [info] java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError
[2012-05-21 18:21:59] [info] : java/lang/Object
[2012-05-21 18:35:16] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2012-05-21 18:35:16] [info] Running Service...
[2012-05-21 18:35:16] [info] Starting service...
[2012-05-21 18:35:16] [info] Error occurred during initialization of VM
[2012-05-21 18:35:16] [info] java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError
[2012-05-21 18:35:16] [info] : java/lang/Object
[2012-05-21 18:45:25] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2012-05-21 18:45:25] [info] Running Service...
[2012-05-21 18:45:25] [info] Starting service...
[2012-05-21 18:45:25] [info] Error occurred during initialization of VM
[2012-05-21 18:45:25] [info] java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError
[2012-05-21 18:45:25] [info] : java/lang/Object
[2012-05-21 18:46:29] [info] Procrun (2.0.4.0) started
[2012-05-21 18:46:29] [info] Running Service...
[2012-05-21 18:46:29] [info] Starting service...
[2012-05-21 18:46:29] [info] Error occurred during initialization of VM
[2012-05-21 18:46:29] [info] java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError
```

Comment: Provide your error log?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError can be due to a number of different causes, but the most common is having a mismatched set of JAR files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this information:-

1. Cross check `classpath` and `path's` are properly setup
2. Verify JVM is properly installed
3. May be `rt.jar` might be missed

At present these are the point coming into mind.

Better if you provide Error LOG information, it will be much easier to trace out the problem.

Comment: I did check class path and JVM appears correct since Apache starts and serves up HTML pages.  There I had URL reference problems due to the re-hosting.  I am expecting the similar stupid mistake in my Tomcat configuration / setup.  I did not check for standard jar files, just my own app's jar.

Answer (score 0):

I have not quite found the solution, but I think I have confirmed the problem with the help of these two websites:

[Blog entry that discussed solving this problem generically.](http://geekycoder.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/java-tips-adventure-in-resolving-the-java-error-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm/#comment-3240)

[Java Tester - displays the java versions as s/w will see on your local machine.](http://javatester.org/version.html)

The java-tester website pointed out that Oracle changed versions on May 3, 2012

> NOTE: On May 3, 2012 Oracle changed the version of Java installed by default on Windows from 6 to 7. 
>   The last edition of v6 installed by default was Update 32. The first default edition of v7 was Update 4.
>   By late May 2012, version 7 update 4 was available to Linux users at java.com. 
>   OS X seems stuck on Java 6 from Apple ...

I will update this answer when I get to the solution.